# Collapse UITableViewCell on second click

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to expand a UITableViewCell with this function, calling from didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
     if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil &&
       [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
        return 128;  
    return 43;  
}
```

Clicking on a cell expands it, clicking on another cell collapses to old and expands the new cell. So far so good. But I also want to collapse the cell, when clicking on an expanded cell, and don't know how?

As a bonus: the content of a not-expanded-cell is shown, overlapping the cell below. How can I prevent showing content that should be cropped by the size of a collapsed-cell?

Comment: Have you tried cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to check in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:…`, if `indexPath` is equal to `selectedCellIndexPath`, then set `selectedCellIndexPath` to `nil`.

You didn't provide that code, so I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a BOOL declared in your header and then int your

```
-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath {
if(your condition) {

BOOL Selected = YES

[tableView reloadRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
  }
}
```

and in

```
-heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath {

if(indexPath.Section == TheOneYouWant && indexPath.row == TheOneYouWant && Selected)
return YourHeight;
else if (indexPath.Section == TheOneYouWant && indexPath.row == TheOneYouWant && !Selected)
return yourOtherHeight;
}
```